# Success method not triggered on Collection fetch with params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am new to backbone, i am having a very strange problem. Issue is that when i pass params to collection fetch, it never triggers the success call back method, but without params it triggers.

here is my code, with this it never goes in success call back but if i remove data params, then it goes to success call back and give alert message.

P.S, i know there is another way of doing with with settting the `reset` attribute and binding the collection in view but i can't use it.

```
showPhotoList: (projectId) =>
    @photoLists.fetch data: $.param(project_id: projectId),
      success: @renderPhotoList,

      error: =>
        alert "Error occured while fetching the project"


  renderPhotoList: =>
    alert "hellow render"
```

Comment: Does it trigger the error callback when you pass parameters?

Comment: @Puigcerber, no it doesn't... but without params both success and error works like a charm

Comment: Why do you need `$.param`? the `fetch` and the `sync` methods take care about it. you simply need `data: {project_id: projectId}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CoffeeScript doesn't do what you think it does. This:

```
@photoLists.fetch data: $.param(project_id: projectId),
  success: @renderPhotoList,

  error: =>
    alert "Error occured while fetching the project"
```

really means this:

```
@photoLists.fetch(
  { data: ... },
  { success: ..., error: => ... }
)
```

so your `success` and `error` callbacks are being passed to [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) in the *second* argument, not the *first* options argument. `Collection#fetch` only knows about one options argument so it never sees your callbacks.

You need to be very careful and consistent with your CoffeeScript formatting:

```
@photoLists.fetch
  data: $.param(project_id: projectId)
  success: @renderPhotoList
  error: =>
    alert "Error occured while fetching the project"
```

And if that's really your error callback then you don't need a fat-arrow (`=>`) on it, it doesn't care what `@` (AKA `this`) is so an unbound function (`error: -> ...`) would suffice.